# Adding value to a dictionary that its values is a list

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> providerLevelChanges = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

By having the key of an item in the dictionary how can I add a value to the list of its values?

I am doing something like this but it is wrong.

```
providerLevelChanges["someKey"].Add("someNewValue");
```

Comment: "but it is wrong"; what is wrong about it?

Comment: Yes, what is the error or exception ?

Comment: It should work. What is wrong in it?

Comment: I get null exception

Comment: @Bohn That sounds like you might have done a `provierLevelChanges.Add("someKey", null)` at some point.

Comment: @juharr : Yes, that was the issue, I had done a containskey for the dictiorary but had added "null" to initialize the list part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to make sure the list exists and add it if it doesn't

```
List<string> list;
if(!providerLevelChanges.TryGetValue(someKey, out list))
{
    list = new List<string>();
    providerLevelChanges.Add(someKey, list);
}

list.Add(someNewValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

You first need to initialize the list, you can use [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the key already exists, otherwise add it:

```
List<string> list;
if (!providerLevelChanges.TryGetValue("someKey", out list))
{
    list = new List<string>();
    providerLevelChanges.Add("someKey", list);
}
list.Add("someNewValue");
```

If you want to initialize the dictionary in one line you can use the collection-initializer:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> providerLevelChanges = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    { "someKey", new List<string>{"someNewValue"} }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create your list of value first.
Try something like

```
List<string> theList = new List<string>()
if (!providerLevelChanges.TryGetValue("somekey", out theList))
{
   //The key is not present in the dictionary 
   providerLevelChanges["somekey"] = theList;
}
theList.Add("someNewValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

Without complete code and an error message, it's tough to tell where your issue but here's a full example:

```
//instantiate the Dictionary
Dictionary<string, List<string>> providerLevelChanges = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

//Add the first item to the Dictionary - notice the empty List<string>
providerLevelChanges.Add("someKey", new List<string>());

//Add a value to the new List<string>
providerLevelChanges["someKey"].Add("someNewValue");
```

The important part is that I'm adding a complete element to the Dictionary before trying to access it.